# Find and replace char in multiple csv files

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet

I have several csv files in one folder. I want to add these files into one excel files with multiple worksheets. 
Before I add them in my excel sheet I want to replace `.` with `,`, because of my convention in excel.

However, the code below gives me:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportCSVs()
'Summary:   Import all CSV files from a folder into separate sheets
'           named for the CSV filenames

Dim fPath   As String
Dim fCSV    As String
Dim fnd As Variant
Dim rplc As Variant
Dim wbCSV   As Workbook

'add your find and replace values!
'#############################
fnd = "."
rplc = ","

Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'speed up macro
'path to CSV files, include the final \
'#############################
fPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\Data\23-3-2015_Data\"

fCSV = Dir(fPath & "*.csv")                 'start the CSV file listing

    Do While Len(fCSV) > 0
        Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fCSV)  'open a CSV file and move
        'find and replace the . by ,
        For Each wbCSV In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
         wbCSV.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
         LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
         SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        Next wbCSV
        ActiveSheet.Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)

        fCSV = Dir                  'ready next CSV
    Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set wbCSV = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any recommendation what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your reply!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
'add to your Dim statements:
Dim ws as Worksheet

'change your Do loop to:
Do While Len(fCSV) > 0
    Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fCSV)  'open a CSV file and move
    'find and replace the . by ,
    For Each ws In wbcsv
     ws.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
     LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
     SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next ws
```

Also, I find it's easier to debug things if you leave the `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` commented out until everything's working. You're not all that worried about execution speed when you're debugging.

**An alternative loop** since you're opening a CSV, there can only be one worksheet in it, this should simplify things a bit:

```
Dim DestBook as workbook

Set DestBook = ThisWorkbook
'other setup stuff...

Do While Len(fCSV) > 0
  Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fCSV)  'open a CSV file and move
    'find and replace the . by ,
  wbCSV.worksheet(1).Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
       LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
       SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
  wbcsv.move after:=DestBook.sheets(DestBook.sheets.count) 
  wbCSV.close
  vFCSV = Dir
Loop
```

I also noted that the move was moving it to `ThisWorkbook` and there's no guarantee what that would be when you got there. So, I declared a new `WorkBook` variable and assigned it to `ThisWorkbook` before doing anything, that way you're 100% certain where you're moving it to. I also closed the CSV that we opened, just for some tidying up.

Comment: Thx! I tried it, but it does not start running. The program also does not give me an error message...

Comment: Which part(s) of this did you try? Have you stepped through it in the debugger (put your cursor in the Sub(), press F8 to execute a line of code)? That will tell you where it's doing something that you weren't expecting it to do...

Comment: Good catch, Branislav!

Answer (score 2):

wbCSV is workbook object not worksheet .
try this

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
  for each ws in activeworkbook.worksheets
```

Comment: you are using `option explicit`, you must declare the `Dim ws As Worksheet`

Answer (score 2):

In the error line `For Each wbCSV In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` you want to loop through all the worksheets but you are using `wbCSV` which is declared `As Workbook`.

To solve the type mismatch add a new variable  `Dim wsCSV As Worksheet` and use this new variable in the loop as a reference for each worksheet.

### The loop could look like this :

```
For Each wsCSV In wbCSV.Worksheets
    wsCSV.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Next wsCSV
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! I changed it, but nothing happens when I run the program. I also get no error message at all ;(

Comment: I think that @Freeman 's answer will help you. It's more complete than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your method for going through wbCSV, never did it but doesn't seem right...

I cant suggest you use what I posted here just by switching "xml" to "csv" :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184595/loop-on-all-files-in-the-same-directory-then-detect-extension-type/29187762#29187762

I think it'll be a rather good start for what you have to do! ;)